# obtener texto de uno de los contenedores de una clase pasando el raton sobre una imagen de uno de esos contenedores

Tags: javascript

Muy buenas, 
digamos que tenemos un bloque (`div`) dividido en seis más. Cada uno de estos contiene una `img`, `h2` y `p`:

Después queremos que, al pasar el ratón sobre una de las imágenes, aparezca un `alert` con el contenido del `p` del mismo contenedor.
 OK. Pues el único modo que he encontrado para poder acceder al `p` es colocando la clase(`evento`) en el contenedor para acceder al texto de `p` con (`this.lastElementChild.innerHTML;`).

Algo así:

```js
var evento = document.getElementsByClassName('evento');
var par = document.getElementsByClassName('par');

for(i = 0; i < evento.length; i++){
    evento[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
        var texto = this.lastElementChild.innerHTML;
        alert(texto);
    })
}
```

```html
<div id="bloque">
    <div class="evento">
        <img src="img/icono engranaje.png" alt="imagen A">
        <h2>web designs</h2>
        <p class="par">aaaaaaaaa</p>
    </div>
    <div class="evento">
        <img src="img/icono estadistica.png" alt="imagen E">
        <h2>web development</h2>
        <p class="par">eeeeeeee</p>
    </div>
    <div class="evento">
        <img src="img/icono etiqueta.png" alt="imagen I">
        <h2>responsive designs</h2>
        <p class="par">iiiiiiiiiiiiii</p>
    </div>
    <div class="evento">
        <img src="img/icono nube.png" alt="imagen O">
        <h2>edit sections</h2>
        <p class="par">ooooooooo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="evento">
        <img src="img/icono pause.png" alt="imagen U">
        <h2>databases</h2>
        <p class="par">uuuuuuuuuuuuuu</p>
    </div>
    <div class="evento">
        <img src="img/icono perfil.png" alt="imagen EPA">
        <h2>android</h2>
        <p class="par">epaepaepa</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Pero no encuentro la forma de que, al pasar exclusivamente por la imagen, pueda obtener el texto de `p`

Mil gracias!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Opción con **QuerySelector**:

Si lo que quieres es que el evento se active al hacer el `hover` de la imagen puedes quedarte con todos los elementos `img`:

```
var evento = document.querySelectorAll('.evento img');
```

`querySelectorAll` devuelve una lista de elementos, por lo que después tendrás que iterar de igual manera en ella.

Y para coger el texto, conociendo la estructura puedes acceder al padre y de ahí coger el `p`, con otro `querySelector`, a diferencia del `querySelectorAll` este devuelve el primer elemento.

```
var texto = this.parentElement.querySelector("p").innerHTML;
```

---

**Snippet:**

```js
var evento = document.querySelectorAll('.evento img');
for(i = 0; i < evento.length; i++){
    evento[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
        var texto = this.parentElement.querySelector("p").innerHTML;
        alert(texto);
    })
}
```

```html
<div id="bloque">
    <div class="evento">
        <img src="img/icono engranaje.png" alt="imagen A">
        <h2>web designs</h2>
        <p class="par">aaaaaaaaa</p>
    </div>
    <div class="evento">
        <img src="img/icono estadistica.png" alt="imagen E">
        <h2>web development</h2>
        <p class="par">eeeeeeee</p>
    </div>
    <div class="evento">
        <img src="img/icono etiqueta.png" alt="imagen I">
        <h2>responsive designs</h2>
        <p class="par">iiiiiiiiiiiiii</p>
    </div>
    <div class="evento">
        <img src="img/icono nube.png" alt="imagen O">
        <h2>edit sections</h2>
        <p class="par">ooooooooo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="evento">
        <img src="img/icono pause.png" alt="imagen U">
        <h2>databases</h2>
        <p class="par">uuuuuuuuuuuuuu</p>
    </div>
    <div class="evento">
        <img src="img/icono perfil.png" alt="imagen EPA">
        <h2>android</h2>
        <p class="par">epaepaepa</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias,

Perfecto!